# Modifying an existing script to accept a different parameter

Tags: php

Thank you for your time.

I am trying to modify an existing PhP script to accept a user input string on line 23. Right now it only accepts numbers put into the array.

```
 <?php
 function isJewishLeapYear($year) {
 if ($year % 19 == 0 || $year % 19 == 3 || $year % 19 == 6 ||
  $year % 19 == 8 || $year % 19 == 11 || $year % 19 == 14 ||
  $year % 19 == 17)
return true;
   else
return false;
 }
 function getJewishMonthName($jewishMonth, $jewishYear) {
   $jewishMonthNamesLeap = array("Tishri", "Heshvan", "Kislev", "Tevet",
                            "Shevat", "Adar I", "Adar II", "Nisan",
                            "Iyar", "Sivan", "Tammuz", "Av", "Elul");
   $jewishMonthNamesNonLeap = array("Tishri", "Heshvan", "Kislev", "Tevet",
                               "Shevat", "", "Adar", "Nisan",
                               "Iyar", "Sivan", "Tammuz", "Av", "Elul");
 if (isJewishLeapYear($jewishYear))
return $jewishMonthNamesLeap[$jewishMonth-1];
else
return $jewishMonthNamesNonLeap[$jewishMonth-1];
 }

 $jdNumber = gregoriantojd(12, 12, 2016);
 $jewishDate = jdtojewish($jdNumber);
 list($jewishMonth, $jewishDay, $jewishYear) = explode('/', $jewishDate);
 $jewishMonthName = getJewishMonthName($jewishMonth, $jewishYear);
 echo "<p>The Jewish date of death is $jewishDay $jewishMonthName $jewishYear</p>\n";
 ?>
```

What I would LIKE is the line

```
 $jdNumber = gregoriantojd(12, 12, 2016);
```

to accept instead of specific numbers, USER INPUT. I was thinking that you could use the $userinput, but that threw an error of expected 3 strings, got one.

Again this is not my forte, but I am thrown into the mix as back-end for a project. I do not expect code written for me, just nudges in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to get user input, but I really like [jQuery-UI's datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). And if it is set, then you can parse the date with [the DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#class.datetime) and [format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) its output as inputs to `gregoriantojd`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php
 function isJewishLeapYear($year) {
 if ($year % 19 == 0 || $year % 19 == 3 || $year % 19 == 6 ||
  $year % 19 == 8 || $year % 19 == 11 || $year % 19 == 14 ||
  $year % 19 == 17)
return true;
   else
return false;
 }
 function getJewishMonthName($jewishMonth, $jewishYear) {
   $jewishMonthNamesLeap = array("Tishri", "Heshvan", "Kislev", "Tevet",
                            "Shevat", "Adar I", "Adar II", "Nisan",
                            "Iyar", "Sivan", "Tammuz", "Av", "Elul");
   $jewishMonthNamesNonLeap = array("Tishri", "Heshvan", "Kislev", "Tevet",
                               "Shevat", "", "Adar", "Nisan",
                               "Iyar", "Sivan", "Tammuz", "Av", "Elul");
 if (isJewishLeapYear($jewishYear))
return $jewishMonthNamesLeap[$jewishMonth-1];
else
return $jewishMonthNamesNonLeap[$jewishMonth-1];
 }

if(
    isset($_GET['datepicker']) &&
    $datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $_GET['datepicker']) 
){
    $jdNumber = gregoriantojd($datetime->format('m'), $datetime->format('d'), $datetime->format('Y'));

    $jewishDate = jdtojewish($jdNumber);
    list($jewishMonth, $jewishDay, $jewishYear) = explode('/', $jewishDate);
    $jewishMonthName = getJewishMonthName($jewishMonth, $jewishYear);
    echo "<p>The Jewish date of death is $jewishDay $jewishMonthName $jewishYear</p>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways. They both require that you convert your $userinput variable into an array.

if: `$userinput = "12 6 2016";`

You can do:

```
$input = explode($userinput, ' ');
$jdNumber = gregoriantojd($input[0], $input[1], $input[2]);
```

The other way is to pass the array as a list of inputs:

```
$jdNumber = call_user_func_array('gregoriantojd', $input);
```

Not tested, but should work.